# furstenberg's proof of szemeredi's theorem

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, reference-request, ergodic-theory

I have been struggling for a long time to understand the ergodic theoretical proof of szemeredi's theorem.
What is the highly recommended reference for furstenberg's proof of szemeredi's theorem ?

Comment: I would have a look at the "Szemeredi" tag on Terry Tao's blog. His discussion is spread across a number of different posts but is usually pretty readable.

Comment: look up yufei zhao's exposition of it. it's very nice

Comment: @mathworker21 what is the exposition title ?

Comment: @Neilhawking http://yufeizhao.com/research/szemeredi-expo.pdf

Comment: @mathworker21 thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First half of「Ergodic Theory with a view towards Number theory」, written by Manfred Einsiedler and Thomas Ward, is aimed at introducing ergodic theory to a beginner up to the point of Furstenberg's proof.